# GPS Data Parsing

Tags: raspberry-pi, c

I got my hands on a USB DeLORME Earthmate GPA LT-20, I want to use it as part of a mobile GPS ratification unit, Raspberry Pi based.  I have been able to access the raw serial data but am at odds with an effective means of parsing the data into a usable format.  the current plan is just to have it printed on screen in a meaningful way.  just looking at ideas.  Bellow is a sampling of the data, i have altered the GPS location data to remove the particular location of testing.  Perfer to code in C

I have read the following refrence sites:

http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GPS_satellites

```
$GPRMC,050229.000,A,3XX8.647,N,11XX1.282,W,0.1,0.0,140518,11.7,E*4B
$GPGGA,050229.000,3XX8.64662,N,11XX1.28205,W,1,06,1.5,725.48,M,-28.4,M,,*5D
$GPVTG,0.0,T,11.7,M,0.1,N,0.1,K*79
$GPGSV,3,1,09,10,34,240,34,13,24,054,00,15,47,086,26,16,25,292,30*77
$GPGSV,3,2,09,20,79,310,31,21,65,345,37,26,25,260,00,27,11,320,00*78
$GPGSV,3,3,09,29,46,147,34,,,,,,,,,,,,*4C
$PSTMECH,21,7,20,7,15,7,29,7,10,7,00,0,16,7,00,0,00,0,00,0,00,0,00,0*5C
```

Comment: We are not freelancer here to write a pièce of software

Comment: Please describe what you want to identify by parsing and please show what you already have. As it is the question seems very broad - almost a "write code for me".

Comment: Can't you just integrate it with `gpsd` then you can see the data in a couple of sensible formats and also access it from any application using TCP.

Comment: Yunnosch - I realize it fairly broad, no i am not asking for anyone to "write code for me"  I am quite sure I could find open source if all I wanted was plug and  play code.  I am looking for direction and pointers.  I often tackle too large a project to expand my understanding and skills.  Mark - The device I am attempting to construct will have 0 internet connections, and must be fully self contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this information:

```
`"$GPRMC,050229.000,A,3008.647,N,11001.282,W,0.1,0.0,140518,11.7,E*4B"`
```

Use `strtok` for parsing:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    char buf[256];
    char *array[20];
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp))
    {
        if(strstr(buf, "$GPRMC"))
        {
            int count = 0;
            char *token;
            token = strtok(buf, ",");
            while(token != NULL)
            {
                array[count++] = token;
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                if(count == 20)
                    break;
            }

            printf("Latitude : %s %s\n", array[3], array[4]);
            printf("Longitude : %s %s\n", array[5], array[6]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Latitude : 3008.647 N
Longitude : 11001.282 W
```

Comment: Barmark, thank you for this pointer, I see how you showed to split the data, using the comma as a deliminator and knowing the specific location within the generated array.